# Open source archiver with integrated Error Correction Code

Tags: file-compression

Is there an open source archiver with integrated error correction code? (preferably windows 7, linux is ok, too)

presently the most stable procedure for me seems to be archiving with 7z and then creating recovery file sets using multipar (http://multipar.eu/).

So far I've seen, that rar-archives including a recovery record get unrecoverable if the change is in sensitive areas, even if only single bits are changed. Solution with additional par files is far more stable and at the same time notably smaller w.r.t. to archived data volume, alas it has several drawbacks:

- process requires an additional program
- process generates two additional files

I'd prefer the approach the rar authors have chosen (including recovery record in achive file), but it should be more resilient against damage

Comment: Are you looking for a solution for a specific OS. Or should/must it be platform-independent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for *Integrity Checking* (ex: CRC32) and creation of *Recovery Records* (ex: [Reed-Solomon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction) - ECC) in the [Comparison of file archivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_archive_formats#Comparison) page.

## Some examples:

### [FreeARC](http://freearc.org/)

- Provides Reed-Solomon error correction (same type as PAR) with user-defined size.;
- Does smart things like switching between LZMA, PPMD, TrueAudio, Tarnado and GRzip algorithms based on file type;
- I've seen it 'in the wild' a few times and used it for a few compression tests. It's somewhat popular with the demo-scene crowd;
- Linux development seems to be largely abandoned and there's yet to be a 64 bit binary;
- Sourceforge page provides [infected binaries](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/A37CEEDCDA14532C004C488521C328C731574EF80128923288E5822CFB9C5BB2/analysis/)... The [FreeARC Download page](http://freearc.org/Download.aspx) looks clean, but I'd suggest running them through https://www.virustotal.com/ just in case.

## [DAR](http://dar.linux.free.fr/)

- Integrates [PAR](https://github.com/Parchive/par2cmdline), as described in the [Command-line Usage Notes](http://dar.linux.free.fr/doc/usage_notes.html#Parchive);
- Good multi-platform support and is available on most UNIX and Windows platforms by the looks of it. Ubuntu also provides packages. Pulls 'par2' as a dependency.

## [RAR](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm)

- You could also continue using RAR and increase the size of the recovery record to 10%. At 10% with RAR 5.x+ it should be 'on-par' with PAR :-). In theory anyway.
- See [RAR 5 Release notes](http://www.rarlab.com/rarnew.htm): "RAR 5.0 recovery record is based on Reed-Solomon error correction codes. If recovery record size is large enough, 5% and more, the new error correction scheme provides much higher resistance to multiple damages comparing to RAR 4.x"